# How to remove an property in propertygrid[hide property]

Tags: vb.net

I want to remove an property in propertygrid (like cursor property and other ...)
How?
[image]

Comment: Not actually sure you can, but why?  Maybe with some context for why hide these properties we could offer some workarounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the [`Browsable` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8) to your property and set it to `False`, e.g.

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Thing
    Inherits Component

    Public Property VisibleProperty As String

    <Browsable(False)>
    Public Property HiddenProperty As String

End Class
```